# how to build Multiple File Upload in yii2 for the all types of files?

Tags: php, yii2

How to build a post model and controller with Multiple File Upload in yii2 with the all types of files  when creating a new post that I can get a Post with slider?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For Upload Multiple Files, follow the official tuto: https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/blob/master/docs/guide/input-file-upload.md

With files in folder, you can use [Yii2 Galery](https://github.com/2amigos/yii2-gallery-widget) or bootstrap\Carousel [(in this post)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28803436/sliding-image-using-yii2).